# Quadratic Formula placement for Java

Tags: java

I am having trouble with NAN and Real roots placement.  Here's a screenshot of my results:

[image]

This is what I am trying to do :

- Prompt the user to input the coefficients of the quadratic equation and print out the equation in standard form: ax^2+bx+c=0 (2 pts)
- Calculate the roots of the equation. If `a=0`, print a message indicating the equation is not a valid quadratic equation. Otherwise, calculate the roots based on the discriminant of the quadratic formula.
- When the discriminant is non-negative, print out the real root(s). Note: print the smaller root first. When the discriminant is negative, calculate the real and imaginary parts of the complex roots separately and then print the roots in standard complex 'a+bi' form. Note: print the complex root with the +bi first. (8 pts)

  ```
  public class Quadratic {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
      double a = input.nextDouble();
      double b = input.nextDouble();
      double c = input.nextDouble();

      double discriminant = Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c;

      System.out.println("a:");
      System.out.println("b:");
      System.out.println("c:");
      System.out.println("Equation: " + a + "x^2+" + b + "x+" + c + "=0");

      //If a=0, print a message indicating the equation is not a valid quadratic equation.
      if (a == 0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid quadratic equation.");
      }
      //When the discriminant is non-negative, print out the real root(s).
      if (discriminant > 0) {
        System.out.println("Real root(s):");
        double root1 = (-b + Math.pow(discriminant, 0.5)) / (2 * a);  
        double root2 = (-b - Math.pow(discriminant, 0.5)) / (2 * a);
        System.out.println("x = " + root2);
        System.out.println("x = " + root1);

      }
      //When the discriminant is negative, calculate the real and imaginary parts of the complex roots separately.
      if (discriminant < 0) {
        System.out.println("Complex roots:");
        double r1 = -b/(2*a);
        double r2 = Math.sqrt(-discriminant)/(2*a);
        System.out.println("x = " + r1 + "+" + r2 + "i");
        System.out.println("x = " + r1 + "-" + r2 + "i");
      }   
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `else` when either this or that is the condition to be followed, and non-negative shall include 0, as:

```
if (a == 0) {
    System.out.println("Invalid quadratic equation.");
} else if (discriminant >= 0) { // non-negative
    System.out.println("Real root(s):");
    ...
} else  {
    System.out.println("Complex roots:");
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you, changing it to "else if (discriminant >= 0) {" solved it. The last statement is fine if I leave it alone, both works!

Comment: @SeraAng Cool, if it helps do accept it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

**First problem**: you go on to compute and display roots even when the equation is not quadratic (`a == 0`);

**Second problem**: you excluded the case of `discriminant == 0` by taking `discriminant < 0` to indicate complex roots and `discriminant > 0` to mean real roots.

The correct logic to handle both issues is:

```
if (a == 0) {
    // it's not a quadratic: give message 
} 
else {
    if (discriminant < 0) {
        // compute and display complex roots
    } 
    else { // disciminant is zero or greater...
        // compute and display real roots
    }
}
```